# Run powershell script in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

I've seen similar questions here.

One question had an accepted answer of

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;
child = spawn("powershell.exe",["c:\\temp\\helloworld.ps1"]);
child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("Powershell Data: " + data);
});
child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
});
child.on("exit",function(){
    console.log("Powershell Script finished");
});
child.stdin.end(); //end input
```

I'm on Ubuntu so I changed it to

```
        var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;
            child = spawn("/usr/bin/pwsh",["/srv/webroot/pauseRS.ps1"]);
            child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
                console.log("Powershell Data: " + data);
            });
            child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
                console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
            });
            child.on("exit",function(){
                console.log("Powershell Script finished");
            });
            child.stdin.end(); //end input
```

I dont get any errors when I run the node package but it doesnt seem to be running the powershell script. Nothing is logged in the console.

The powershell script just runs a web request. When I run the powershell script by itself it runs fine and works as expected. Trying to call the powershell script with node is not giving any errors and not producing any results.

Node 12.21.0

Comment: Powershell on Ubuntu? Why?

Comment: I dont know bash and I made the script on Windows before moving to Ubuntu.

Comment: No errors and no results, but does the `node` process exit? As an side: It looks like `child.stdin.end();` isn't required here, since you're not providing stdin input programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I tried spawning a powershell script that simply outputs `Hello World!` using node.js (12) in Ubuntu. Following is the code. It seems to work just fine. Can you share the content of your ps1 file?

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const ls = spawn('/usr/bin/pwsh', ['hello.ps1']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```